# How is it possible that piece of code that was working is now ignored?

Tags: javascript, json, tabs

I have coded a ajax based "JS TABS" containing .JSON file like 10 months ago, now wanted to reuse it, and can't find out why it's not working. I haven't touched it since and don't know where is the bug.

When i click the button to render products nothing prints out - except console telling me:  `items is undefined` = so i moved it inside `function changeCategoryItems(categoryId) { }` well no errors but nothing renders...can someone help me ?

Here is a codepen reference of what i mean: https://codepen.io/Contemplator191/pen/WNwgypY
And this is JSON : https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5f634e0c302a837e95680846

If codepen is not suitable/allowed here is whole JS for that

```js
let items = [];
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('section.products');

buttons.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click',event => {
    changeCategoryItems(event.target.dataset.category);
  });
});


function changeCategoryItems(categoryId) {
    let items = [];
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('section.products');
    const viewItems = (categoryId == 0 ) ? items : items.filter(item => item.category == categoryId);
    wrapper.innerHTML = "";
    viewItems.forEach(item => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute("class", "product");
      div.innerHTML = createItem(item);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    });
};


function createItem(item) {
  return `

  <div class="product__img">
    <img src="${item.img}" class="">
  </div>

  <div class="product__name _tc">
    <h4 class="">${item.heading}</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="text-desc product__desc">
    <p class="">${item.description}</p>
  </div>


  <div class="product__bottom-content">
    <span class="product__info">${item.info}</span>
    <a href="" role="button" class="btn btn--teal btn--animated product__btn">${item.btn}</a>
  </div>

  `
}


fetch('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5f634e0c302a837e95680846')
.then(function (res) { return res.json() })
.then(function (data) {
  items = data.items;
  changeCategoryItems(1);
});`
```

Answer (score 2):

In your fetch you're trying to assign data.items to the items variable but the api doesn't return data with an items node so items is undefined. It's possible the api changed their return format since the last time you used it which would explain why it worked previously.

this seems to fix it

```
.then(function (data) {
  items = data;
  changeCategoryItems(1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you som much :) Although i do not understand first sentence,  I had it first through myjson.com api  - well it ceased to exist or moved... - is that the reason why it changed its return format ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in this line:

```
items = data.items;
```

Now, the returned value is an array, hence you can use it as it is.

The updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/gaetanoM/pen/abNajLE)

Comment: Thank you :) So it was object "data" with method items before but how is that possible that it works as an array now ?